# nsinvalidargumentexception' reason 'an avplayeritem cannot be associated with more than one instance of avplayer'

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I am using

> MPMoviePlayerController

for play video and in this I used custom seek bar to jump video. but when I continuously do the seeking forward and rewind then application crashed and throw below error:

> nsinvalidargumentexception' reason 'an avplayeritem cannot be
>   associated with more than one instance of avplayer'

So please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating a new avplayer each time you jump? And add some example code to your question :)

Comment: may same question here http://bit.ly/NGXMy3

Comment: No. I am not creating avplayer each time. Its created only once when view did load.

Answer (score 13):

Had same issue, try setting ContentURL after Setting the SourceType like below,

```
moviePlayerController_ = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
moviePlayerController_.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[moviePlayerController_.moviePlayer setContentURL:url];
```

Source: [devforums.apple.com/message/467199](http://devforums.apple.com/message/467199)

Comment: +1 this definitely solved my issue, but i should point out that my crash occurred only if i was using MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming.  If i used MPMovieSourceTypeFile, then i was able to initWithContentURL: without incurring any crash.

Answer (score 6):

Had same experience. realized movieSourceType was set incorrectly. For example, movieSourceType was set to MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming when it should have been MPMovieSourceTypeFile for a movie embedded in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and in my case the problem is that I couldn't tell if the movie is a file or a stream (the URL doesn't tell), so I set it to `MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown` and that also solved the problem. It has that value by default but if you start playing a movie of either type, it internally changes the type to either stream or file and if you now change the URL without setting the correct type or manually setting type back to `MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown`, you'll get an exception.