# MPMoviePlayerController blank on layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

i need to play the MPMoviePlayerController over a layer of UIView. But only sound that came out, no video.

```
theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[theMovie prepareToPlay];

theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 150);
[theMovie setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
[theMovie setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
 theMovie.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[theMovie setContentURL:movieURL];

[self addSubview:theMovie.view];
[theMovie play];
```

I only got a black screen, and only audio. Is this because i called the UIView as layer and not as subview? Because my requirement is to call the UIView as layer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good,try adding this:

```
 [_openingMovie setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
```

Hope this helps

**Edit**

try setting ContentURL after Setting the SourceType like below,

```
moviePlayerController_ = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
moviePlayerController_.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[moviePlayerController_.moviePlayer setContentURL:url];
```

This code snap is from:
[An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041260/an-avplayeritem-cannot-be-associated-with-more-than-one-instance-of-avplayer)

Comment: Hi, i got crash with messsage Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'.Thanks..

Comment: try setting ContentURL after Setting the SourceType like below moviePlayerController_ = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
moviePlayerController_.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[moviePlayerController_.moviePlayer setContentURL:url];      (From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041260/an-avplayeritem-cannot-be-associated-with-more-than-one-instance-of-avplayer)

Comment: Hi, now the crash gone but the screen is still blank, only the audio plays.thanks btw..

Comment: Did u try to set it to full screen? are u sure the url is good? what type is it?

Comment: No, i set the setFullScreen=NO, and yes the url is good, i already check. And its a mp4 file.

Comment: Did u try playing on a different UIView?